# Dart null safty Assertion operator issues

Tags: dart, variables, null

So I've been following along to a fireship course on dart and I got the error: "Null check operator used on a null value". Was just wondering why? Here is the code:

```
String? answer;

String result = answer!;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's working exactly as intended.

The `String? answer;` declaration introduces a nullable variable with a current value of `null`.

The `answer!` expression reads that value, checks whether it's `null`, throws if the value is `null`, or evaluates to the non-`null` value if it isn't `null`.
Since the value is indeed `null`, that operation throws the error you see.

The `!` is the "null check operator". It's used on the value `null`. The error message is actually quite precise.

To *avoid* that, make sure the `answer` variable has a non-`null` value when you use the `!` operator on it. (Often you won't need the `!` for local variables because assigning a non-`null` value to the variable also promotes the variable's type to non-nullable, but there are cases where the compiler can't see that assignment, for example if it happens in a callback function.)